# Using touch screens with FPS

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Has anyone tried using a touch screen monitor with CoD:BO? Is it possible? How does it compare with using a mouse? Does it turn the game into a bit of a whack-a-mole kind of game, constantly just trying to poke enemies that you see on the screen?

I imagine that it would be difficult because you've now tied up an entire hand with just aiming (and possibly pulling the trigger). On my mouse I have enough buttons to aim, shoot, grenade, knife, ADS, and switch weapons. I don't know how you could manage all of that with a touch screen set-up. Or could you play "bare bones", basically trading off the ability to grenade, switch weapons, ADS, and knife so that you would only be shooting but be able to use the touch screen for that.

If anyone has experience doing this with other FPSs I'd be interested in hearing about that as well. I don't plan on actually trying this set-up, but I am curious if others out there are doing it.

Comment: I think the biggest problem would probably be turning. You'd need some way to handle touching the edge of the screen to signify you wanted to turn left/right, or you'd have to use separate keys for it or something. The mouse usually handles that, too, and I could see that being fairly awkward with a touch screen.

Comment: There are shooters on the iPad... Though they are mostly [rail shooters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Rail_shooters)

Comment: There are quite a few FPS on the DS (including World at War and two Modern Warfare titles). You use the touch screen (bottom screen) to aim, just as you would use a mouse, while you move your character using D-pad. It works well in my opinion.

Comment: @sarmackie @Torpesh Black Ops is on the DS also.

Comment: +1 for "just trying to poke enemies that you see on the screen?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only games designed specifically for use with touchscreen have any chances to work with it.

I really don't see any way how you'd play FPS on touch screen, given that in FPS the crosshair is always in center of the screen, while mouse rotates the view. In case of games designed for touch screens, the view is fixed, while cross hair follows your finger.

Apart of that, in case of CoD:BO, for full control you need 23 different actions triggered by buttons (either mouse or keyboard). There is no way to do that on touch screen.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually tried doing this. It just won't work. You must keep in mind that a touchscreen touch usually translates to you moving your mouse to that point (which translates to turning your head around in an FPS).

There is no way to calibrate your mouse moving distance on a touch to an accurate point and shoot mechanism.

When I tried to do this I ended up spinning like a ballerina and just looking plain silly :D

Answer (score 0):

In general, it won't work. Most games linking camera movement to mouse movement place your cursor in the center of the screen and then (one or two frames later) compare that position with the new position to get the exact movement. As a random example, without getting to technical: The cursor moved 3 pixels to the left, so rotate the camera by 3 degree to the left. The cursor moved 3 pixels to the top, rotate the camera upwards by 3 degree. Think you get the hang of it. Using a touch screen moves the mous immediately which would result in a HUGE rotation. I didn't try it, but rather than shooting the target you clicked at you'll turn around several times while shooting once and possibly getting kicked off the server due to weird/impossible data.